# Datepair - Input Element Inside Table Row

Tags: jquery

I am using the TimePicker and DatePair.js plug-in script from the site below and I tried the given example on the page and confirmed the example works.

http://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js/

This example works on the page, so it is confirmed all the include files are set up correctly.

```
<p id="basicExample">
    <input type="text" class="date start" />
    <input type="text" class="time start" /> to
    <input type="text" class="time end" />
    <input type="text" class="date end" />
</p>

<script>
    // initialize input widgets first
    $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
        'showDuration': true,
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
    });

    $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
        'format': 'm/d/yyyy',
        'autoclose': true
    });

    // initialize datepair
    var basicExampleEl = document.getElementById('basicExample');
    var datepair = new Datepair(basicExampleEl);
</script>
```

The problem is my form has a table, and when I place this date/time inputs inside the table row, it is not working. I tried like this below and it was no luck.  Please advise.

```
<p id="basicExample"> 
    <tr>        
        <td class="right"><b>Start Time: </b></td>
        <td class="left">      

           <input type="text" name="StartDate" id="StartDate"  value="09/02/2016" class="date start" />
            <input type="text" name="StartTime" id="StartTime" value="2:00pm" size="20" class="time start"/>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="right"><b>End Time: </b></td>
        <td class="left">                   
           <input type="text" name="EndDate" id="EndDate"  value="09/02/2016>"  class="date end"/>
            <input type="text" name="EndTime" id="EndTime" value="3:00pm" size="20"  class="time end"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</p>
```

Thank you,